# nginx wordpress sub-domain lets encrypt

Tags: wordpress, ssl, encryption

I ran wordpress site with this SSL tutorial. 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have **example.com** domain. and I create **test.example.com** sub-domain.
There's problem with connect with test.example.com it shows **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** on chrome.

How can I connect sub domain to existed lets encrypt. and 
further more, How can I connect second-domain **example2.com** to SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your settings on your nginx server directives?

The server directives for both port 80 and port 443 should be refer to the subdomain instead of your domain. Like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    return 301 https://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
    }   

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    ....
}
```

As for your second domain example2.com, it depends on what you purchased is single-domain SSL certificate or multi-domain certificate.

Comment: I solved with [this](https://wlcdesigns.com/2016/10/wordpress-multi-site-ssl-setup-nginx-using-lets-encrypt/).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Let's Encrypt FAQ](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/) Let’s Encrypt doesn't offer wildcard certificates:

> Let’s Encrypt offers Domain Validation (DV) certificates. We do not
>   offer Organization Validation (OV), Extended Validation (EV), or
>   wildcard certificates, primarily because we cannot automate issuance
>   for those types of certificates.

If you have requested certificate just for `example.com` it won't work for `www.example.com` or `test.example.com`.
You need to explicitly declare every domain or subdomain in your request using **-d** parameter of `letsencrypt` or modern `certbot`:

```
letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d example.com -d test.example.com -d www.example.com
```

You can request certificate for different domains the same way:

```
letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d example.com -d www.example.com -d example2.com -d www.example2.com
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I can't access test.example.com / And also example2.com redirected to example.com

Comment: @Snowcat Jung Show your nginx config, please. There must be some mistake.